# Biblatex custom chem-angew style (footnote)

Tags: biblatex

I want to customize `chem-angew` biblatex bibliography style, to include also a footnote. I like the way this style outputs bibliography and make the citation (I'm using `\autocite{foo}`) but I would like to have a little excerpt of the citation in the footnote.

As an example, this is the reference in the bibliography section:
[image: Example of bibliography]

I would like to have in the *footnote*, on the page where I make the citation, something like:

[image: Footnote example]

How can I achieve this?
I've tried using `\footcite{foo}` but this doesn't work. Also `\footnote` is not suitable for this, because I want it to be automated with bibtex.
I've tried also `citesyle=verbose-note,bibstyle=chem-angew`, which is the nearest style I have managed to achieve. But the first citation in the text is verbose and I don't want it (I need only the number in the text).

---

Additional details: I'm not using `biber` engine, but `bibtex` one. I'm using Miktex with TekWorks on Windows.

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[
    hyperref=true,
    url=false,
    isbn=false,
    backref=false,
    style=chem-angew,
    maxcitenames=3,
    maxbibnames=100,
    backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliografia}{}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum bibliography.\autocite{foo}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibligrafia.bib file content:

```
@article{foo,
    title={Spent coffee bioelastomeric composite foams for the removal of Pb2+ and Hg2+ from water},
    author={Chavan, Asmita A and Pinto, Javier and Liakos, Ioannis and Bayer, Ilker S and Lauciello, Simone and Athanassiou, Athanassia and Fragouli, Despina},
    journal={ACS Sustainable Chemistry \& Engineering},
    volume={4},
    number={10},
    pages={5495--5502},
    year={2016},
    publisher={ACS Publications}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, a Minimal Working Example would help us help you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: @EladDen added additional details :)